# Building a Typescript type using Javascript variables for the key names

Tags: typescript

Imagine a Typescript database lib which allows a developer to `add` record attributes/columns/keys to be returned from the database. Is it possible to return a type which includes the keys that the developer `add`ed?

Given a record definition like this...

```
type GenericRecord = { [key: string]: string | number };

type UserRecord = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
```

... the user should be able to load a record like so. The goal is for the return type to be `{name: string, age: number}` or `{name: string} & {age: number}` or something similarly specific.

```
const userLoader = new RecordLoader<UserRecord>();
const user = userLoader.add("name").add("age").load();
```

Here is my best effort:

```
class RecordLoader<FullRecord extends GenericRecord, PartialRecord extends Partial<FullRecord> = {}> {

  private attrsToLoad: (keyof FullRecord)[] = [];

  constructor(attrsToLoad: (keyof FullRecord)[] = []) {
    this.attrsToLoad = attrsToLoad;
  }

  add(attrName: keyof FullRecord) {
    this.attrsToLoad.push(attrName);

    // I believe this is where the magic should happen. Is there a way to use the
    // variable `attrName` to add a specific key name and value type to `PartialRecord`?
    return new RecordLoader<FullRecord, PartialRecord & { [attrName: string]: string }>();
  }

  load() {
    return loadData<PartialRecord>(this.attrsToLoad);
  }
}

function loadData<PartialRecord extends GenericRecord>(keys: (keyof PartialRecord)[]) {
  // Data would be loaded and added to return object here.
  return {} as PartialRecord;
}
```

Within the `add` method, I cannot figure out a way to create that new intersected type in a way that specifies the actual key passed into the method. Is it possible for the code and the type system to communicate in this way?

I could turn the `add` method into a generic and pass the key and type into it, but I'd like to avoid the redundancy of writing the key name in the generic and the method and defining the value type in the record and in the generic.

```
  add<T extends Partial<FullRecord>>(attrName: keyof FullRecord){
    this.attrsToLoad.push(attrName);
    return new RecordLoader<FullRecord, PartialRecord & T>();
  }

const userLoader = new RecordLoader<UserRecord>();
const user = userLoader.add<{name: string}>("name").add<{age: number}>("age").load();
// Type of user is `{name: string} & {age: number}`
```

Comment: Make the type of `attrName` a generic parameter: https://tsplay.dev/wEpqbW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider distributing `N` if `N` could be a union for more accurate/predictable results:

```
  add<N extends keyof FullRecord>(attrName: N) {
    this.attrsToLoad.push(attrName);

    // distribute N over the Pick for more predictable types when N is a union
    return new RecordLoader<FullRecord, PartialRecord & (N extends N ? Pick<FullRecord, N> : never)>();
  }
```

---

As for `load`, it's a little icky to get working. However, if you enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`, the original code should work without any problems.

```
  load() {
    // enabling exactOptionalPropertyTypes - loadData<PartialRecord> would work
    return loadData<{
      [K in keyof PartialRecord]-?: Exclude<PartialRecord[K], undefined>;
    }>(this.attrsToLoad);
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgJQmg9kgJlALxQDeUA2gNYQgBcUAzsKvAOYC6DzrbUAPlHgBXALYAjZFAC+AbgCwAKCWhIUAKqNkWXAWJklUKCnzcWKdgsVH4AQ1EQzvK0dttHQsZKRW5SpWgANraMjFA6ePgAMji2+MgAPIZQAGLCgYERehAAHsAI+GFwiKiY2JEANMkACrZIwCi2meXZeQVhtfWNgQlpGVn4AHz6pNJVisOkyWCoAG62+VALLIwAKjgxcQwAFDQgOABmqenNuvgAlBQc+ldWybjwPMJowHjby0hrG7GmULu0h2O-RaFyuNw45wM1iMUGAAAsUIwAHQfL6bQgkVHrdEuGT+aFxfAJAByUFy+XghSge0BfVOkUG72ALGJ9g8xMhU2hRnhiJRzM+2J+SLAwkYcKZLLZ5zu3KgAHp5VB8IjzOJhItSThZlJ4dBqugqFADngoKI8NAZhAVS9bOJAtBVBAwgB3OEIKCkxFLKDCeAoHDwZJGJAQYDCJDwIQQF3hEHoxJ0gYVKCdBpNAZQABkf1J5PanqgAH5U4beidk57hgxEDqkOdGTLktJ8UZAj9tpzgwqlQg7YELHxcrYXgB5MANQNNapIHCQeogVbgZ1QAC0UHbcQAIgtbAk090BsMXTh0oQT0gqN3Q+HIxufjvgHuuTCYRQANLGKM0o4HjMgjhVyLBgAFEciCYR4n3Op03pAgPw4FM-XiA4LGtQZcSMaRGV5ZEsW+OIm2hFtFBIpQDj9F4AyjTd8EfPc-zgwh80pIoEGQdAj22ZI9kYHYf1TGDDxBS5EKULtoUVKB6KgE8zygSR7zia0lkpJZ8HiQhXigG8IyjHBxAAK2wYAoHdUMkWSXS71GJYOiE-8zl8fEHmYX0tCQBMkH0RBYwGLyEk0bQQUbKxXNMsUpBISLPJ+ZAUQ0hIACI7AcJKBCgJKTCSxkUrZJLzgS-BtiStwIAKpFaM7KwpKXNRARi4wwgAA1IVKPB4QdpGzMgyprLxkGkZqlCAA)

---

To disallow adding duplicate properties, you can exclude the keys already in `PartialRecord`:

```
  add<N extends Exclude<keyof FullRecord, keyof PartialRecord>>(attrName: N) {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgJQmg9kgJlALxQDeUA2gNYQgBcUAzsKvAOYC6DzrbUAPlHgBXALYAjZFAC+AbgCwAKCWhIUAKqNkWXAWJklUKCnzcWKdgsVH4AQ1EQzvK0dttHQsZKRW5SpWgANraMjFA6ePgAMji2+MgAPIZQAGLCgYERehAAHsAI+GFwiKiY2JEANMkACrZIwCi2meXZeQVhtfWNgQlpGVn4AHz6pNJVisOkyWCoAG62+VALLIwAKjgxcQwAFDQgOABmqenNuvgAlBQc+ldWybjwPMJowHjby0hrG7GmULu0h2O-RaFyuNw45wM1iMUGAAAsUIwAHQfL6bQgkVHrdEuGT+aFxfAJAByUFy+XghSgAFEckFhPEEntAX1TpUoMyjp0Gk0BoNBu9gCxifYPMTIVNoUZ4YiUULPtifkiwMJGHDBcLRec7lKoAB6PVQfCI8ziYSLUk4WZSeHQaroKhQA54KCiPDQGYQY0vWziQLQVQQMIAdzhCCgpMRSygwngKBw8GSRiQEGAwiQ8CEEGD4RB6MSrIGFSg3O6AygADI-qTye0I1AAPwlh29E5FiPDBiIa1Ic4C7XJaT4oyBH7bCVJ-WGhC+wIWPi5WwvADyYAaCaa1SQOEg9RAq3AQagAFooKO4gARBa2BKl3kg4bBnDpQhPpBUScptMZs8-K-AG9JRhGEKAAaWMTNORLOoeTZAgOGPBsGFpelGTvOD8DAjhi1jeIDgsL1BlxIxpAFGVkSxb44gHaEh0UOilAOWMXnjTNz3wf8b3Q8ta0pIoEGQdA+W2ZI9kYHYoO4kFLmwpQJ2hA0oE4qAnxfKBJF-OIvSWSklnweJCFeKAv3TTMcHEAArbBgCgMMUyRZITJ-UYlg6GCyxBXx8QeZgYy0JB8yQfREBzAZAoSTRtAfccrB8mzVSkEgEoCn5kBRfSEgAIjsBxMoEKBMpMTKBWy0VMvOdL8G2TK3AgcqkXYmKlEUg81EBZLjDCAADUgco8Hh52kSsyFqrsvGQaQuvxRTkG3JAlGSwLKuqvr6sJFayu1IA)

Answer (score 0):

Props to @kelsny for the solution!

```
  add<T extends keyof FullRecord>(attrName: T) {
    this.attrsToLoad.push(attrName);
    return new RecordLoader<FullRecord, PartialRecord & Pick<FullRecord, T>>();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach which reduces the allowed attributes to add when they are already added and also allows removal of attributes, is immutable and is not constraint to a specific key type:

Perhaps this could be cleaner, but this is the best I could do it.

```
type UserRecord = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

function loadData<TIn, TOut>(attributes: (keyof TIn)[]): TOut {
    console.log(attributes);
    return {} as TOut;
}

class RecordLoader<T, TExclude = T, TOut = {}> {

    constructor(private attributes: (keyof T)[] = []) {
    }


    add<TKey extends keyof (TExclude | T)>(attribute: TKey) {
        if (this.attributes.includes(attribute)) {
            throw new Error('attribute already exists.');
        }
        const attributes = this.attributes.slice();
        attributes.push(attribute);
        return new RecordLoader<T, Omit<TExclude, TKey>, TOut & Pick<T, TKey>>(attributes);
    }

    remove<TKey extends keyof (TOut | T)>(attribute: TKey) {
        const index = this.attributes.indexOf(attribute);
        if (index === -1) {
            throw new Error('attribute does not exist.');
        }
        const attributes = this.attributes.slice();
        attributes.splice(index);
        return new RecordLoader<T, Pick<TOut, TKey> & TExclude, Omit<TOut, TKey>>(attributes);
    }

    load(): TOut {
        return loadData<T, TOut>(this.attributes);
    }
}

const userLoader = new RecordLoader<UserRecord>();
const user = userLoader
    .add('age')
    .add('id')
    .add('name')
    .load(); // ["age", "id", "name"]

const user2 = userLoader
    .add('age')
    .add('age') // compile time error
    .load();

const user3 = userLoader
    .add('age')
    .remove('age')
    .add('age')
    .load(); // ['age']
```